# How can I hide an embedded font?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a situation in AS3 where I am required to embed a font but the .tff font file to be distributed with the software can't be seen by the user for copyright reasons.  At the moment I embed the font using metadata in a sub folder of the application and it all works nicely, but I am not sure as how to hide the .tff?

Thanks

Christopher Grigg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you embed a font into the swf, you do not have to give the ttf file with your application. All information are embedded within the swf to render the font.

How you do the embedding? Like this?

```
[Embed(source = '../assets/myFont.ttf', fontName = "MyFontName", embedAsCFF = "false")]
public var MyFont:Class;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  Yes I embed the font as you have demonstrated.  If I provide access to fonts on another project in flex, the fonts will all be included in the SWF too?

Comment: Don't know how you `use this method on another project in flex`, but yes, if the class which holds the embed statement is compiled into the other project it will be included. You could also have a resource swf with embedded fonts, and dynamically load the swf into your application.

Comment: thanks, I ended up using a library project to create a SWC file.